# Wordpress multisite 301 redirects on requests to files

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have a wordpress multisite installation, and I want to migrate some old sites to this installation. The problem is that the paths are changing in wordpress. I want to create redirections from old paths to new, in order not to drop the SEO ranking. There are some plugins that do this job but the problem is that the plugins don’t make redirects on requests to files. For example, I would like to make a redirect from mysite.com/find-us.php to mysite.com/findus. Every site has its own domain name and the htaccess is common. Also, I would like to be able to redirect files like photos, giving the old path of the photo and the new path. Does anybody have any idea on how can I do this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are various methods you can do that by editing .htaccess files or through plugins. You can understand more by reading this
https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-create-redirects-with-wordpress

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use .htaccess because it is common to all sites (as I mentioned it is a multisite installation). SEO Redirection plugin is not developed for multisite installations and Redirection plugin doesn't work with .php and image extensions. Thanks for the answer.